# Create three images based of the user's surname

Tags: javascript, css, image, random, hash

I'd like to change the name that the user enters into a 3 digit number(000-999), then display 3 images based of the numbers given.

If the number made is 015, then the first image displayed would be 000.jpg, the second 010.jpg and the third would be 005.jpg. Id like the same result each time a name is entered and I'd like to update on real time if possible. I hope this helps clear things up, I'm still trying to figure out the best way. Thanks

The aim is to create an illustration comprised of 3 images that combine together, mix and match style.

Here's what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/x19mLe73/

Ideally I'd like the user to input their name and the images to change to the respective numbers.

```
function doSomeStuff() {

    document.getElementById("LastName").text = "Connor"; // Simulate User Input
    var lastName = document.getElementById("LastName").text;
    var myPics = document.getElementById("myPics");

    var sum = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<lastName.length;i++)
    {
      sum += lastName.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    sum = (sum%1000);
    var firstPic = (sum + "").split('')[0] + "00.jpg";
    var secondPic = "0" + (sum + "").split('')[1] + "0.jpg";
    var thirdPic = "00" + (sum + "").split('')[2] + ".jpg";

    var imgToAdd1 = document.createElement("img");
    imgToAdd1.src = firstPic;
    imgToAdd1.alt = firstPic;
    myPics.appendChild(imgToAdd1);

    var imgToAdd2 = document.createElement("img");
    imgToAdd2.src = secondPic;
    imgToAdd2.alt = secondPic;
    myPics.appendChild(imgToAdd2);

    var imgToAdd3 = document.createElement("img");
    imgToAdd3.src = thirdPic;
    imgToAdd3.alt = thirdPic;
    myPics.appendChild(imgToAdd3);
}

doSomeStuff();
```

Comment: what happened to your fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by changing your `.value` assignment to `.text`. The images will still be broken, but now they point to the correct 3-digit filenames.

```js
window.doSomeStuff = function() {

    var lastName = document.getElementById("LastName").value;
    var myPics = document.getElementById("myPics");

    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < lastName.length; i++) {
        sum += lastName.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    sum = (sum % 1000);
    var firstPic = (sum + "").split('')[0] + "00.jpg";
    var secondPic = "0" + (sum + "").split('')[1] + "0.jpg";
    var thirdPic = "00" + (sum + "").split('')[2] + ".jpg";

    myPics.innerHTML = "";
  
    var imgToAdd1 = document.createElement("img");
    imgToAdd1.src = firstPic;
    imgToAdd1.alt = firstPic;
    myPics.appendChild(imgToAdd1);

    var imgToAdd2 = document.createElement("img");
    imgToAdd2.src = secondPic;
    imgToAdd2.alt = secondPic;
    myPics.appendChild(imgToAdd2);

    var imgToAdd3 = document.createElement("img");
    imgToAdd3.src = thirdPic;
    imgToAdd3.alt = thirdPic;
    myPics.appendChild(imgToAdd3);

}
```

```css
img {
    border: 1px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;    
}
```

```html
<input id="LastName" value="Connor" />
<div id="myPics">
</div>
<button onclick="doSomeStuff();" >Go</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! thats great. Is there any way to have the previous images removed when the user inputs another name?

Comment: @JordanConnor You will need to clear the output element using `myPics.innerHTML = "";`. I just edited my answer to add that, check the example again!

Comment: "a few bugs I found", there's just one, that you need to use `.value` on the input and not `.text`. That's also all you've changed from the original code, you should say that so that OP knows what they did wrong. And you still have a `.text` assignment in your current code.

Comment: @JordanConnor You're feature creeping. Don't be a feature creep http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions

Comment: @Jan Thanks, I meant to go back and explain that `.value` should be used instead of `.text`, but I ended up forgetting. And I just fixed the assignment.

Comment: Works Great! Thanks Guys. Yeah ill definitely tell him, he was a great help. yeah @Jan i know its bad etiquette. The thread was kind of dead apart from me and. Don't have internet at home currently so i'm in a pub briefly haha.
i hope to use this as part of my design project, I'll put you in the source code.

Thanks again.

Comment: @JordanConnor Glad this answer ended up working for you! Don't forget to mark it as accepted, thanks!

Comment: @JordanConnor you shouldn't update the question with the correct answer, instead just mark the correct answer (this one) as "accepted"